# Render first few objects of JSON file in reactjs/redux

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm getting data from a json file which has many user objects. I was successful in retrieving data from this json file and render in my react app. I have a need to render only first 4 objects, how can i do it?

I have used a for loop but it was resulted in rendering all objects 4 times rather than first 4 objects.

My code.

```
export const FriendSuggestionsHomeList = ({suggestedList}) => {

    const noFriendsSuggested = (
        <div>
            <p>
                Sorry you have no friends in your contacts list
            </p>
        </div>
    );

    const showFriendsAvailable = (
        <div>
            {suggestedList.map(user => <FriendSuggestionsHomeCard suggestedList={user}/> )}
        </div>
    );

    return (

        <div>
            {suggestedList.length === 0 ? noFriendsSuggested : showFriendsAvailable}
        </div>
    )
};
```

I have done something like this but resulted in printing all objects 4 times

```
var row = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        row.push(suggestedList.map(user => <FriendSuggestionsHomeCard suggestedList={user}/>));
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's printing all objects 4 times Why?

Because you are running `map` inside `for` loop, so it will be like 4 * all the objects by map.

You need to remove the `map` part, write it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4 && i < suggestedList.length; i++) {
    row.push(<FriendSuggestionsHomeCard key={i} suggestedList={suggestedList[i]}/>);
}
```

Or use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
{
   suggestedList.slice(0, 4).map((user,i) => 
       <FriendSuggestionsHomeCard key={i} suggestedList={user}/> )
}
```

**Note:** Assign the unique key to each element.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get only part of an array:

```
const showFriendsAvailable = (
    <div>
        {suggestedList
            .slice(0, 4) // limits the array to its first 4 members
            .map(user => <FriendSuggestionsHomeCard suggestedList={user}/> )}
    </div>
);
```